# How can i create an incremental query in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, increment

I need some useful examples to understand how to create a query which will bring in only incremental data on a weekly basis. This data will be pulled in incrementally using date & time column.

Comment: There are no incremental queries in SQL. You'll have to write a query that loads data that was created/modified after the last query based eg on a timestamp or maximum ID returned by the last query. SQL Server also offers [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in all versions and editions. When change tracking is enabled the database keeps the change (Insert, Delete, Update) for each PK combination in a system table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have a table `customer`

```
create table customer(id int, name varchar(10), age int, created_on date, last_modified_on datetime)
create table customer_inc(id int, name varchar(10), age int, created_on date, last_modified_on datetime)

insert into customer(id,name,age,created_on,last_modified_on )
values(1,'a',54,'2022-01-01','2022-01-01 00:00:00.000')
values(2,'a',52,'2022-01-01','2022-01-01 00:00:00.000')
values(3,'a',53,'2022-01-01','2022-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

| id | name | age | created_on | last_modified_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 54 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | b | 52 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | c | 53 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 |

you pull all these record as full load into your `inc` table

Now the record id 3 gets updated and new record gets inserted

| id | name | age | created_on | last_modified_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 54 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | b | 52 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | f | 53 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-27 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | y | 30 | 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-27 00:00:00.000 |

Now you need to identify these new data using last_modifed_on by getting the maximum value of last_modified_on from customer_inc

> Solution 1:

*use merge logic for the below dataset*

```
select * from customer where last_modified_on > (select max(last_modified_on) from customer_inc)
```

> Solution 2:
> Always load the previous day(D-1) data as per your requirement.

*use merge logic for the below dataset*

```
select * from customer where last_modified_on > cast(getdate()-1 as date)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. This helps a lot.